# Systemd daemon-reload on new service

Tags: systemd

I am writing my first systemd service (oneshot to run on startup).

I am confused whether I need to run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` after I created (not modified) a new service file in `/etc/systemd/system` directory before running `sudo systemctl start ...`

Some examples of creating a service that I found on the internet mention `systemctl daemon-reload`, some don't.

Comment: When you write a new unit, the first time you activate it, you do not need to issue `systemctl daemon-reload`. However, when you subsequently change a unit that already exists you have to tell systemd to read all unit files from disk again by running `systemctl daemon-reload`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether `systemctl daemon-reload` is needed or not depends on how your service behaves. From man page for [systemctl(1)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/systemctl.1.html),

> daemon-reload
>
> Reload the systemd manager configuration. This will
> rerun all generators (see systemd.generator(7)), reload all unit
> files, and recreate the entire dependency tree.

So, for example, say your service have dependencies, or conflicts. Then you may use `daemon-reload`. If it's a simple service, it may not need this.

When you first `enable` your service, the system manager configuration is reloaded. So, if you want to test your service using a `start`, you don't need `daemon-reload` once you have `enable`d your service.

Again, from man page for systemctl(1),

> enable UNIT..., enable PATH...
>
> This will create a set of symlinks, as
> encoded in the [Install] sections of the indicated unit files. After
> the symlinks have been created, the system manager configuration is
> reloaded (in a way equivalent to daemon-reload), in order to ensure
> the changes are taken into account immediately.

If you want to do a service unit file change and retest, you may want to do a `daemon-reload` depending on what those changes are. It's okay to do a `daemon-reload` anyway, and the system might ask you to do it when you `start` your service.